# Magic Matrices?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, magic-square

Can you determine any number of magic squares, that when treated as matrices, can be applied mathematical operations to return a new magic-matrix?

**You cannot use the same matrix twice!**

*The answer should be given as a mathematical equation using the matrices you find.*

> Magic squares follow the general magic square rules, they contain 1, .., $n \times n$ once, and each row, column, and diagonal sum to 1 number.

**Allowed Operations: Add, Subtract, Multiply, Exponention, Logarithms**

Comment: Must an n by n magic square contain each of the numbers 1 through $n^2$ exactly once? What are the allowed operations?

Comment: @Lopsy See my edit.

Comment: Do you mean the operations to act on matrices or their elements?  Precisely what operations are allowed?

Comment: Anybody have any idea who downvoted? I honestly don't see any reason...

Comment: I actually upvoted, but perhaps the reason is that this feels like a totally arbitrary question to ask, riding on the recent "magic square" popularity train. I doubt you knew the answer when you posted the puzzle (correct me if I'm wrong). It turns out that the puzzle actually has a nice answer. IIRC the downvotes came in before Julian and I posted our answers, and without the context of our answers, the puzzle admittedly does look like a meaningless number-bashing mess.

Comment: @Lopsy You are right, I didn't know the answer. But *I wanted to know!* isn't that the point of SE Q&A sites, do help others find answer?

Comment: @warspyking "Are there any integer solutions to $2^x+\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor = y^4$?" Scrap. "Are there any integer solutions to $x^n+y^n=z^n$?" 358 years of interest. The monk asks, "Why is one question more worthy than another?" His master answers, "Now you have asked a worthy question."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible.

Fix $n$. Let $M$ denote the set of all $n$-by-$n$ magic squares. $M$ is *really huge* - for $n=6$, we have $|M| \sim 10^{19}$ (see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A006052)).

Consider all $2^{|M|}$ sums of subsets of $M$. Each one is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix whose entries are positive integers which are at most $n^2|M|$. There are $(n^2|M|)^{n^2}$ matrices which fit this description.

If $|M|$ is large enough, then $2^{|M|} > (n^2|M|)^{n^2}$. Then by Pigeonhole, two of the sums of subsets are equal. Using this equality, we can express one of the magic squares as a sum/difference of others.

What is "large enough"? Taking logs on the inequality, we find that even $|M|=O(n^3)$ is large enough for sufficiently large $n$. For $n=4,5,6$ this works. I cannot find any references to back this up, but I bet there are enough magic squares that this works for all $n\geq4$.

Answer (score 5):

If we consider two magic squares that differ by a rotation distinct, then here's an example with $3\times 3$ squares. Let
$$
M_1=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}4&9&2\\3&5&7\\8&1&6\end{array}\right],\,M_2=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}8&3&4\\1&5&9\\6&7&2\end{array}\right],\,M_3=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}6&1&8\\7&5&3\\2&9&4\end{array}\right],M_4=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}2&7&6\\9&5&1\\4&3&8\end{array}\right].
$$
Then we can compute
$$
M_1+M_3=M_2+M_4=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}10&10&10\\10&10&10\\10&10&10\end{array}\right],
$$
so that the equation $M_1+M_3-M_2=M_4$ gives a solution to the problem.

Comment: Your finished product doesn't include the numbers 1, ..., $n \times n$ not to mention, you didn't even add properly? 4 + 8 + 6 + 2 don't equal 10...

Comment: @warspyking Read the answer more carefully. He is not just adding all four matrices.

Comment: Oh oops, I misread that = as a + (how on earth did I do that? Lol!)